# Notificaciones Web para mensajes de Inbox

Tags: característica-nueva

Según el popular sitio [Can I use](http://caniuse.com), la API de notificaciones ya es completamente soportada en las últimas versiones de los navegadores más usados (sacando MSIE que es irrelevante xD):

[image]

Y me surgió la idea de implementarlas en el sitio para mostrar los mensajes del inbox de los usuarios.

---

#### Justificación

StackOverflow, como todo sitio, aparte de su [principal propósito](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal/254973), quiere ofrecer una buena experiencia de usuario, tanto en diseño como en funcionalidad. La implementación de [Notificaciones Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API) significaría un aporte a este propósito.

Algunas veces contestamos una pregunta y pasamos a hacer alguna cosa. Luego de unas horas, vemos que el OP ha comentado nuestra respuesta sin obtener más ayuda. Si bien no es obligación responder, creo que si tenemos el tiempo para ayudar, podemos hacerlo más rápido. Las Notificaciones Web ayudarían en este escenario, informándonos de algún evento en el sitio.

#### Ventajas

- Mayor interacción con el usuario aunque esté fuera del sitio.
- Al ser notificaciones instantáneas, podremos acudir a tal evento o al menos estaremos al tanto de qué ha pasado.
- Los OP tendrían más probabilidad de obtener asistencia más rápido al comentar respuestas.

#### Demostración

El siguiente código, es un ejemplo muy sencillo de una notificación web, emulando una notificación de un comentario a alguna respuesta nuestra.

[Demo Notificación](http://jsbin.com/hehehorato)

Comment: Hay muchos scripts de usuarios que hacen esto, disponibles en los stores de Chrome y Firefox.. E incluso más detalles de cada uno en http://stackapps.com/ .. Y otra opción es usar la aplicación mobile, que tiene notificaciones

Comment: La app móvil no es una opción del todo en mi opinión. Es incómodo estar viendo el móvil para ver nuevas notificaciones. Sobre las extensiones, las he probado; mas la idea es tener uno propio para el sitio, sin depender de los mantenedores de esas extensiones.